# Does GHC-mod have to use full names for types?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghc-mod

I'm trying to use the `ghc-mod` vim plugin to do type/syntax checking etc. However, I found that `ghc-mod` always uses full paths of types in the error messages, for example:

```
test.hs|71 col 13 error| Couldn't match type ‘Data.Text.Internal.Text’                                                                                   
||                with ‘[GHC.Types.Char]’
|| Expected type: containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Map.Base.Map
||                  [GHC.Types.Char]
||                  ([(integer-gmp-1.0.0.0:GHC.Integer.Type.Integer,
||                     integer-gmp-1.0.0.0:GHC.Integer.Type.Integer)],
||                   containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Set.Base.Set
||                     integer-gmp-1.0.0.0:GHC.Integer.Type.Integer)
||   Actual type: containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Map.Base.Map
||                  Data.Text.Internal.Text
||                  ([(integer-gmp-1.0.0.0:GHC.Integer.Type.Integer,
||                     integer-gmp-1.0.0.0:GHC.Integer.Type.Integer)],
||                   containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Set.Base.Set
||                     integer-gmp-1.0.0.0:GHC.Integer.Type.Integer)
|| In the second argument of ‘containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Map.Base.map’, namely
||   ‘zippedMap’
|| In the second argument of ‘(GHC.Base.$)’, namely
||   ‘containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Map.Base.map
...
```

which clutters the screen and it's very hard for me to find out where went wrong. As comparison, this is the error message for the same file using `ghci`:

```
test.hs:71:13:
    Couldn't match type ‘T.Text’ with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: M.Map [Char] ([(Integer, Integer)], S.Set Integer)
      Actual type: M.Map T.Text ([(Integer, Integer)], S.Set Integer)
    In the second argument of ‘M.map’, namely ‘zippedMap’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘M.map
...
```

which is much cleaner. Is there a way to make `ghc-mod` use short names for the types?

Comment: This isn't the observed behaviour for me. Is this still happening for you? Which versions of `ghc` and `ghc-mod` are you using?

Comment: Do you have a self contained example (imports included) that generates output like the above? I think I have an idea what the problem might be, but it is a bit hard to tell only from the output...

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the argument to ghc from ghc-mod as:

```
$ ghc-mod lint *.hs -g -dsuppress-module-prefixes
```

This will send the argument `-dsuppress-module-prefixes` to ghc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing `-dsuppress-module-prefixes` as a GHC option. At some point, it did help me to get rid of module qualifiers in names.